# Reporting an act of vengeance on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, downvotes, serial-voting

I was browsing through the Stack Overflow website and had commented on a few posts requesting the OPs to indent the codes that they had submitted, etc. When I checked after a few minutes, I found out that **some of the questions that I had asked and some of the answers that I had written were downvoted**. Also, I concluded that it was an act of vengeance given the short span of time in which all the answers were downvoted.

Where can I report this act (and if possible, get my reputation back)?

[image: the relevant screenshot]

Comment: To be fair to the OP though, that dupe didn't turn up in the list when entering the title. Not sure why it is necessary to downvote this.

Comment: @Pekka웃, thanks! Not sure if the downvoters will understand it, though. :(